# GCP - Assigning Static External IPs on Marketplace Solutions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, ip-address

I'm having trouble assigning a static IP to a Google Cloud Platform Marketplace Deployment and thought someone here might have some insight.

I have an unassigned static IP ready to go in the same zone as the virtual machine, yet it doesn't allow me to assign that IP to my new Compute Engine VM.

[Image of Deployment Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAzcj.png)

Does anyone have any ideas, or know what might be going wrong? I've refreshed the page and have had the IP reserved for a bit, but still nothing. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should release the IP address after wordpress instance has been created.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address

After you attach the IP address, you should access to the instance using ssh and get the admin password.

--- This is the message that you can see in the ssh console.

```
WordPress One-Click Quickstart guide:
* https://docs.litespeedtech.com/cloud/wordpress
In a web browser, you can view:   
* The new WordPress site: http://34.67.88.XXX
* The phpMyAdmin: http://34.67.88.XXX/phpmyadmin
On the server:
* The default web root is located at /var/www/html
* You can get the MySQL root password and MySQL WordPress user password with com
mand:
   sudo cat /home/ubuntu/.db_password
* You can get the Web Admin admin password with the following command:
   sudo cat /home/ubuntu/.litespeed_password
* The WordPress Cache plugin, LSCache, is located at
   /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/litespeed-cache
* The phpMyAdmin is located at /var/www/phpmyadmin
* A script will run that will allow you to add a domain to the web server and im
plement SSL.
```

Comment: Do you mean reserve? I've tried, but run into issues with network tiers. I'll try to make sense with this, but I don't know if it will. 

If I try to promote that ephemeral IP to static using that guide, I get an error saying that the network tiers of the address and project don't match. I first did it with my default network tier set as standard, but I figured that message might mean that the instance wants to use premium tier. I started with a fresh instance and set my network tier to premium, same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm editing my answer now. I was doing some tests and I reproduced your scenario. After some failed attempts I finally was able to attach the static external ip to the openlitespeed-wordpress instance.

The trick was create the instance without external IP and then reserve the ip attaching it to the instance on the reservation process. I mean, when you are reserving the external static IP you need to put the openlitespeed-wordpress instance name on the "Attached to" section (probably your instance will not be listed in the drop down menu) and then proceed to reserve the IP. Remember that the regions of both, the instance and the IP address should match.

Comment: I'm dying of laughter over here... that bug report was created by me as well! That's the account of the actual instance, so I used that. Funny that you were able to find it.

Comment: Well, it is funny but this is telling you that the bug report has some visibility ;-). I edited my answer....